# SELECT INTO USING UNION QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, derived-table

I want to create a new table in SQL Server with the following query. I am unable to understand why this query doesn't work.

Query1: Works

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

Query2: Does not Work. 
Error: `Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Line 7: Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

```
SELECT * INTO [NEW_TABLE]
FROM
(
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You have to define a table alias for a derived table in SQL Server:

```
SELECT x.* 
  INTO [NEW_TABLE]
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM TABLE2) x
```

"x" is the table alias in this example.

Comment: When I try this, it doesn't give me the sum of number of records of TABLE1 and TABLE2, it's always less. Would you happen to know why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: @Christa - This is likely due to having the same row in both tables, it will only make one record for the union. If you use `UNION ALL` it will not remove duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
into new_table
from table_A
UNION
Select * 
From table_B
```

This only works if Table_A and Table_B have the same schemas

Comment: You can use three (and four if the table is on a Linked Server instance) name format to access other schemas and/or databases.

Comment: I think this is the neatest, simplest answer.  I tried it, assuming that it might only add the rows from table_A to new_table.  I was pleasantly surprised that rows from both table_A and table_B ended up in new_table.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
create table new_table as
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO #Temp1
SELECT val1, val2 
FROM TABLE1
 UNION
SELECT val1, val2
FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: Useful but it doesn't create the table.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one working syntax for SQL Server 2017:

```
USE [<yourdb-name>]
GO

SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE 
FROM <table1-name>
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM <table2-name>
```