# how to use union in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello everyone in SQL if am trying to union two tables in a new one , 
and am taking the columns names from these table which names its going to take for the new table and why ?

**Code:**

```
CREATE  TABLE New AS 
Select Phonenumber from Data 
union 
select PhoneNumber from INFO
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Looks like the DBMS product you are using doesn't support the standard `CREATE TABLE ... AS` syntax.

Comment: You can't use New as table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error suggests me `SQL Server` DBMS if so then you use `SELECT . . . INTO`  statement :

```
SELECT Phonenumber INTO New_table 
FROM Data 
UNION
SELECT PhoneNumber 
FROM INFO;
```

If the `new_table` already exists then you can do instead :

```
INSERT INTO  New_table (Phonenumber)
    SELECT Phonenumber INTO New_table 
    FROM Data 
    UNION
    SELECT PhoneNumber 
    FROM INFO;
```

Comment: new_table doesnt exist yet i am creating a new table so i will have to use create table right ?

Comment: @SamarAlaa. . . If the `new_table` doesn't exists then use first version of query.

Comment: it worked , thank you so much , i have another question , when we do so for multiple  columns which Headers its going to take the one for the 1st table or the second one and why ,, for example if we have table 1 has Name Phone address ,  table 2 has FullName Phonenumber Homeaddress , which headers it going to take for the new table and why ??

Comment: @SamarAlaa. . . In that case you have to explicitly re-name column_name & yes the first `SELECT` statement column_name will use as final `Column_name`.

Comment: so if i didnt name the coloumns it will take the Names in the 1st selecte query ! , perfect thank you so much again u r a life saver :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks correct, assuming your database support `create table as`.  However, `new` could easily be a reserved word in your database.  I would recommend a more informative name.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers AS
    SELECT Phonenumber FROM Data 
    UNION
    SELECT PhoneNumber FROM INFO;
```

In SQL Server (the tag that was recently added), the correct syntax uses `INTO`:

```
SELECT Phonenumber FROM Data 
INTO PhoneNumbers
UNION
SELECT PhoneNumber FROM INFO;
```

Comment: still not working , same error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS' '

Comment: should be a peculiarity of sqlserver
See the answer below
or
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4018727/5273803

Answer (score 1):

you could use  parenthesis

```
SELECT x.* 
  INTO [NEW_TABLE]
  FROM 
(Select Phonenumber from Data 
 union      
 select PhoneNumber from INFO
 ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

For you use union, all the selection groups that you want to use union must have the same number of fields with their own names.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE New_table SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Phonenumber FROM Data 
    UNION
    SELECT PhoneNumber FROM INFO
 );
```

Comment: i wrote this exactly and it gives an error ' msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')' '

Answer (score 0):

You can use with clause like this:

```
with cte
as
(

Select Phonenumber from [Data] 
union 
select PhoneNumber from .[INFO]
)

SELECT Phonenumber INTO dbo.NEW_TABLE
FROM cte;
```